# Access Uint8Array in javascript ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, wcf, filereader

I've got a javascript ArrayBuffer generated from a FileReader ReadAsArrayBuffer method on a jpeg file.

I'm trying to access the UInt32 array of the ArrayBuffer and send to a WCF service (ultimately to be inserted into a database on the server).

I've seen an example here on stackoverflow ([byte array method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoGMs.jpg)) where a UnInt32 array is converted to a byte array which I think would work.

I'm trying to access the [[Uint8Array]] of my arrayBuffer variable below so I can send it to the WCF, but I'm not having much luck.  I've tried:

```
   var arrayBuffer = reader.result[[Uint8Array]];//nope
     var arrayBuffer = reader.result[Uint8Array];//nope
     var arrayBuffer = reader.result.Uint8Array;//nope
     var arrayBuffer = reader.result[1];//nope
```

Any ideas on how to access that [[Uint8Array]] would be appreciated.  When the entire ArrayBuffer is sent to WCF Service I get a 0 byte array -- cant read it

Thanks

Pete

[image]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[Those properties do not actually exist on the ArrayBuffer object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer#Properties). They are put there by the Dev Tools window for viewing the ArrayBuffer contents.

You need to actually create the TypedArray of your choice through its [constructor syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#Syntax)

> ```
> new TypedArray(buffer [, byteOffset [, length]]);
> ```

So in your case if you want `Uint8Array` you would need to do:

```
var uint8View = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now I've got to get the WCF service to read/accept the UIntArray

Comment: getting error     Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer | ArrayLike<number> | SharedArrayBuffer'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBuffer | ArrayLike<number> | SharedArrayBuffer'.ts(2769)

Comment: @Sreeraj_ms you need to specify `arrayBuffer` 's type: 
```var uint8View = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer as ArrayBuffer);```